# PLSQL import JSON and export as a JSON file

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am new to PL SQL. I have set up a virtual box with Database APP Development VM( I think it has everything I need inside, but not sure)
Now I would like to load a json file as a table. 
(Then do somestuff)
Then export it again

Here is the Json File:

```
    [
{
  "id" : 1,
  "created_at" : "Tue Oct 22 16:08:59 +0000 2013",
  "text" : "RT @Piratenpartei: Der @humanErr zur EU Datenschutzverordnung #EUDataP : “Starker EU-Datenschutz darf nicht scheitern” ",
  "lang" : "de",
  "place" : null,
  "retweet_count" : 10,
  "user" : {
    "created_at" : "Mon Jun 03 12:37:14 +0000 2013",
    "description" : "Der  Bezirksverband  Tübingen  im Landesverband Baden-Württemberg",
    "followers_count" : 122,
    "id" : 1479629599,
    "lang" : "de",
    "name" : "BzV Tübingen",
    "screen_name" : "BZV_Tuebingen",
    "url" : ""
  }
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "created_at" : "Sat Oct 19 12:15:54 +0000 2013",
  "text" : "RT @PiratenBW: Unser nächster Landesparteitag findet am 15.02.-16.02 2014 in Heidelberg statt. /s3",
  "lang" : "de",
  "place" : null,
  "retweet_count" : 17,
  "user" : {
    "created_at" : "Mon Jun 03 12:37:14 +0000 2013",
    "description" : "Der  Bezirksverband  Tübingen  im Landesverband Baden-Württemberg",
    "followers_count" : 122,
    "id" : 1479629599,
    "lang" : "de",
    "name" : "BzV Tübingen",
    "screen_name" : "BZV_Tuebingen",
    "url" : ""
  }
}
]
```

By exporting i mean something like this:
http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/formatting-query-results-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Maybe some additional question. 
Is there something like automated import. If the file is larger, and it is not clear what is exactly inside or the documentation is poor.

Maybe I should added what databases software i have set up.
I have got an account here; https://apex.oracle.com
And I have an installation in Virtual Box of APP Development VM this is this one: https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html But maybe I need something else.

I am also looking into Postgre but this Question is regarding Oracle.

Comment: What does "load" and "export" mean to you exactly?  Do you want to create a table with a single JSON column, load one row of data, then run some queries against that table and save the results from your client application (i.e. SQL Developer)?  Do you want to take this JSON document and load it into multiple rows of multiple relational tables (i.e. one row in a `user` table, two rows in a `tweet` table) and then write queries to manipulate relational data and later reconstitute a different JSON document?  Something else?

Comment: Firstly load as a table. I think I would nee to set up a clean new database? right? Maybe there is some automatic function? Then export the whole database as a json document. So someone else could use it.

Comment: Creating an entire database for one JSON document would seem like overkill and I'm not sure what you mean when you talk about exporting an entire database as a JSON document.  Are you really trying to include an entire database (tablespaces, permissions, configuration settings, table definitions, data, etc.)?  Or just some data as in the JSON document you posted.  Are you trying to load the document into a single row of a single table in your database?

Comment: There is a way you can load the entire JSON payload into a single JSON validated column in an Oracle table, then extract elements of the JSON into other column(s) in the same or another table(s). Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: unfortunatelly i cannot upload the json file. In germany i can request data, a company has over me. Well i have requested my data, from REWE its a local supermarket, I got a json file,....its a file over 5 years. What, When, Location, prices, well everthing they have. Is there a "automated" way to load it into database? Its super unstructured, in my opinion.

Comment: Well, the software has the features to make this happen, but it's really up to the technology of where it's coming from. Can you feed the file/data via a web service? You may also appreciate https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/tips-for-parsing-json-in-apex But if it's unstructured, and you want it to be relational, something needs to parse it out. Or just keep it as JSON in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

setup for manipulating json:

```
create table json_from_file (id number, data clob, constraint chk_data_is_json check (data is json));

insert into json_from_file (id, data)
  values ( 1, '{
  "id" : 1,
  "created_at" : "Tue Oct 22 16:08:59 +0000 2013",
  "text" : "RT @Piratenpartei: Der @humanErr zur EU Datenschutzverordnung #EUDataP : “Starker EU-Datenschutz darf nicht scheitern” ",
  "lang" : "de",
  "place" : null,
  "retweet_count" : 10,
  "user" : {
    "created_at" : "Mon Jun 03 12:37:14 +0000 2013",
    "description" : "Der  Bezirksverband  Tübingen  im Landesverband Baden-Württemberg",
    "followers_count" : 122,
    "id" : 1479629599,
    "lang" : "de",
    "name" : "BzV Tübingen",
    "screen_name" : "BZV_Tuebingen",
    "url" : ""
  }
}');
insert into json_from_file (id, data)
  values ( 2, '
{
  "id" : 2,
  "created_at" : "Sat Oct 19 12:15:54 +0000 2013",
  "text" : "RT @PiratenBW: Unser nächster Landesparteitag findet am 15.02.-16.02 2014 in Heidelberg statt. /s3",
  "lang" : "de",
  "place" : null,
  "retweet_count" : 17,
  "user" : {
    "created_at" : "Mon Jun 03 12:37:14 +0000 2013",
    "description" : "Der  Bezirksverband  Tübingen  im Landesverband Baden-Württemberg",
    "followers_count" : 122,
    "id" : 1479629599,
    "lang" : "de",
    "name" : "BzV Tübingen",
    "screen_name" : "BZV_Tuebingen",
    "url" : ""
  }
}');
```

Changing json with id 2:

```
DECLARE
  cl_data       CLOB;
  t_root_object JSON_OBJECT_T;
  t_user_object JSON_OBJECT_T;

  CURSOR cu_get_data is
  select data
    from json_from_file
   where id = 2;
BEGIN

   OPEN cu_get_data;
  FETCH cu_get_data INTO cl_data;
  CLOSE cu_get_data;

  t_root_object := JSON_OBJECT_T(cl_data);
  t_root_object.put('lang','ES'); -- changes "lang" in root object

  t_user_object := t_root_object.get_object('user');
  t_user_object.put('lang','ENG'); -- changes "lang" in root object.user

   cl_data := t_root_object.to_string;

   UPDATE json_from_file -- saving change in database
      SET data = cl_data
    WHERE id = 2;

   COMMIT;
end;
```

Putting all parts back together to export it later:

```
create table exported_data(data clob);
/
declare

cursor cu_parts is
select data 
  from json_from_file;

whole_json clob;
begin

  whole_json := '['||chr(10);
  for json_part in cu_parts loop
    whole_json := whole_json||json_part.data;
  end loop;
  whole_json := chr(10)||']';

  insert into exported_data(data) values (whole_json);
  commit;
end;
```

Comment: It is not creating a rational database model right?

Comment: what do i get after loading the json file? Its still a string in one column?

Comment: No, this is creating table with two columns. First contains id, second contains parts of json

Answer (score 0):

For creating relational database model you can use this:
the select will transform data from json to normal records, and then insert will put it in table. Column json_id tells us from which json it was created.

```
-- creates table for root elements of json
create table root_elem (json_id number, id number,create_at varchar2(100), text varchar2(4000), lang varchar2(10), place varchar2(4000), retweet_count number);


    insert into root_elem(json_id, id, create_at, text, lang, place, retweet_count)
    select jff.id json_id, jt.id, jt.created_at, jt.text, jt.lang, jt.place, jt.retweet_count
    from json_from_file jff
    , json_table(jff.data, '$[*]'
    columns (id path '$.id',
             created_at path '$.created_at',
             text path '$.text',
             lang path '$.lang',
             place path '$.place',
             retweet_count path '$.retweet_count'
             )) jt 



-- create table for user elements (root.user)    
  create table users_elem (json_id number, id number,created_at varchar2(100), description varchar2(4000), followers_count number, lang varchar2(100), name varchar2(100), screen_name varchar2(100), url varchar2(4000));

insert into users_elem(json_id, id ,created_at, description, followers_count, lang, name, screen_name, url)
select jff.id json_id,ida ,created_at, description, followers_count, lang, name, screen_name, url
from json_from_file jff
, json_table(jff.data, '$.user[*]'
columns (ida path '$.id',
         created_at path '$.created_at',
         description path '$.description',
         followers_count path '$.followers_count',
         lang path '$.lang',
         name path '$.name',
         screen_name path '$.screen_name',
         url path '$.url'
         )) jt
```